# How to read from STDIN_FILENO even if terminal is closed?

Tags: linux

Im trying to code a program in Linux to read every input from keyboard, but using `STDIN_FILENO` it only reads those entered in the terminal. What I want is during execution it should read keyboard even if the terminal is closed.

Comment: You mean like a keylogger? You'll need to hook into the keyboard driver and/or dispatcher (at least this is how it's done on Windows, I imagine it's similar on Linux). Normally applications only capture keystrokes directed to their own windows or terminals.

Comment: Are you talking about in a windowing system a process started in one window being able to read all the keyboard strokes in all windows? Doing that will not be easy - you would have to get to an appropriate point within the X11 system to do that. Indeed, the system goes to lengths to make sure that a process in window 1 can't read characters sent to window 2. It isn't clear what you might mean by reading from standard input (STDIN_FILENO) when the terminal is closed.  Maybe I'm misinterpreting what you're up to. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

`STDIN_FILENO` is just a helper macro.

From stdin you recieve stream of bytes that are passed to your program, they doesnt neccessary come from terminal - also can from a file, etc. It's not capturing keyboard. The terminal is capturing keyboard and then passes entered data to your program's stdin.

In order to capture keyboard you will need some other method of receiving events. I guess you are running GUI aka X server; Normally applications create windows and receive events related to them. In order to capture all keyboard events, you will have to go more low-level. Take a look at `xlib` which should be sufficient for you, even though it might not be.